# Command run in ARM rootfilesystem

Tags: command-line, virtualization, arm, beagleboard

i'm on developing ARM board (beaglebone black).

when i was create bootimg image, i just copied the ARM rootfilesystem to booting disk. 
but, I want to run Linux commands as if it were a host PC.

How can i run linux command like install package in rootfilesystem ? (not host PC's rootfilesystem. run command in Rootfilesystem to be copied later from the host PC to the ARM target board. )

is there any ARM environment emulation tool in linux ?

Comment: Please, explain your problem clearly. You can refer this [link](https://www.digikey.com/eewiki/display/linuxonarm/BeagleBone+Black), if you have problems regarding Development on beaglebone black. And as for the emulator, you can use [qemu](https://www.qemu.org).

Comment: What is ARM? Please, explain your problem clearer.

Comment: I use TI AM335x core. (beaglebone black board).
and i want install package to AM335x rootfilesystem before i create the booting image.

in my PC environment, I can just type "apt-get install" or "dpkg -i packagename",
but my Beaglebone black's (AM335x) rootfilesystem (debian, ubuntu) is just file in my PC not Beagleboneblack.

Comment: i try to use qemu.
but qemu seems to not support am335x core, and qemu is emulating image file, not rootfilesystem. thanks you.

Comment: can you tell me more about the problem you are facing with beaglebone black

Comment: @Vijay
when i create booting image, i just copy rootfilesystem i downloaded. 
but i want customizing rootfilesystem using host PC before create booting image . 

i think "N0rbert "'s answer is exactly what i want. thanks for your concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mount the AM335x rootfilesystem and chroot to it with something like:

```
# install QEMU ARM static to the host system
sudo apt-get install qemu-user-static

# mount rootfs
sudo kpartx -a -v rootfs.img
sudo mount /dev/mapper/loop0p2 /mnt

# copy qemu-arm-static executable
sudo cp /usr/bin/qemu-arm-static /mnt/usr/bin/
sudo cp /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/etc/resolv.conf

# prepare for chrooting
cd /mnt
sudo mount --bind /dev dev/
sudo mount --bind /sys sys/
sudo mount --bind /proc proc/
sudo mount --bind /dev/pts dev/pts
sudo rm /mnt/etc/ld.so.preload

# chroot to ARM filesystem
sudo chroot .

# do the stuff inside rootfs
apt-get update
apt-get install mc
```

I have tested this method with Raspberry Pi rootfs.

---

References:

- https://wiki.debian.org/RaspberryPi/qemu-user-static
- http://dev.lab427.net/rpi-raspbian-arm-chroot-on-x86-linux.html

Comment: i use chroot command, and "cat /proc/cpuinfo", there is model name : Intel I7.

the raspberry pi core is not intel cpu. if i execute apt-get install "some package", install correc packages ?.

Comment: Yes, *apt-get* should install correct packages. You have to check output of `arch` if unsure.